# My localStorage.clear(); won't work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple program with `localStorage`. I created a button to reset all the data in the `localStorage`. Unfortunately, it won't work I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");

    if (slot == null) {
        slot = 10;
    }

    document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;

    function reduceSlot() {
        if (slot >= 1) {
            slot--;
            document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;
            localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL";
            document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = reduceSlot;

    function clearLocalStorage(){
        localStorage.clear();
    }
</script>

<body>
    <p id="slot">10</p>
    <a href="javascript:reduceSlot(1)" id="button1">Deduct</a>
    <button onclick="clearLocalStorage()">Clear All</button>
</body>
```

I followed this code in a website but it doesn't run. Most of the websites that I browsed were confusing. I need help.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to bind handlers to elements before they exist. Order matters - put your script at the end of the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onclick="window.localStorage.clear();">Clear All</button>
```

This should work.

Comment: thank you sir, but one problem when i click the button it reduces the slot and it's fine. assuming that the remaining slot is 9, but when i refresh my browser it goes back to 10 but when i click again it is already 8, because i already deducted it earlier. my concern is it is always display the slot to 10 when i refresh the browser. @OPUS

Comment: because of this...Its cleared and becomes zero..then you do this.i dont know why..
`if (slot == null) {
        slot = 10;
    }`

Comment: everytime you load your webpage..the entire script will be run..executing every single line..now clear() makes slot value zero,but your `slot=10` reassigns the variable its value...

Comment: i already deleted the `if (slot == null) { slot = 10; }` but it's the same

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the way you are clearing the data.The problem here is with your logic.Localstorage will make data persist beyond browser close unless you clear it.I am sure you are doing something silly with the code..